# How do i connect a VS2008 MVC project to Vista IIS7 localhost as the web server?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I'm trying to connect my stock standard, default ASP.NET MVC (web) application to the Vista IIS7 localhost web server instead of using Cassini.

I'm trying to find some steps to set this up, etc.

I've installed Vista IIS7 and of course MVC beta, VS2008 & Sp1.

Lastly, i'm hoping to also have multiple solutions use the Vista IIS7 for their own web server's (different, independent web sites).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, now I understand your question ... try this:
right click on project > properties > Web > Servers > Use Local IIS Web server

after selecting that, VS should use IIS as the dev server when launch the debugger, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the nescessary steps:
http://blogs.dovetailsoftware.com/blogs/kmiller/archive/2008/10/07/deploying-an-asp-net-mvc-web-application-to-iis7.aspx

Comment: Nope - doesn't help at all. I know how to install IIs7 on Vista. I need to know how to make VS2008 use it as the web server, for my web _development_.